# how can I retrieve objects of a model that have most related objects in another model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have these two models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Image(models.Model):
    a = models.Foreignkey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField()
```

every object in model Person has one or more images in model Image. I want to retrieve 5 person objects that have most images. How can I do that?

Comment: `a` is a `ForeignKey` to `Person`? If not, how else is `Image` linked to `Person`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry. I changed the name of classes but forgot to change it in the foreign key field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a `ForeignKey` from `Image` to `Person`, you order by the number of related images:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Person.objects.annotate(
    nimg=Count('image')
).order_by('-nimg')[:5]
```

Here the `'image'` part is the [**`related_query_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) in the `ForeignKey`, which is by default the name of the model in lowercase (so `image`), or the value for the [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) if specified.

Comment: that not work. We should use annotate(). [django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet).`Person.objects.annotate(a=Count('image')).order_by('-a')[:5]`